# Adding Markers on Google maps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I followed the tutorial in

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
```

and i managed to load a map into my app.Now i want to add some markers into my app using latitudes and longitudes.How do i do it? I tried something but did not work. The code i tried is below.

This how i was going to do it.But i get a null point exception.What is the reason for that?

```
GoogleMap googleMap = null;

           MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) (activity.getFragmentManager())
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

           googleMap = fm.getMap();

            double latitude = 7.421226;
            double longitude =80.401264 ;

            // create marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

            // adding marker
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/filmhall"
    android:background="@color/grey" >



<fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have a any logcat error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look using this methed we are adding marker on google map

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(22.7253, 75.8655)).title("Indore"));
```

here is example

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class BasicMapDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() 
    {
        if (mMap == null) 
        {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) 
            {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() 
    {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(22.7253, 75.8655)).title("Indore"));
  // here is marker Adding code
    }
}
```

[Example on Google Map](https://github.com/ErNaveen/GoogleMapExample/blob/master/src/com/example/mapdemo/BasicMapDemoActivity.java)

Comment: you should use `getMapAsync(listener)` instead of `getMap()`

Answer (score 1):

```
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = ;
double longitude = ;

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to leave thats why i answered what about question is please check I have used maps in my project and I have used http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 1):

Here my code(it has 4 icons in the map, you just call this class like a fragment in main activity, it will working, **REMEMBER**: create a picture in drawable and name it is "atmpin2.png"):

```
package fragments;

import com.einstein.atm.R;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class FragMapsGoogle extends MapFragment {
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container,
                savedInstanceState);
        map = getMap();
        LatLng place = new LatLng(21, 105.8);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 14.0f));


        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        int w,h;
        this.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.atmpin2);
        float h2w2 = (float)bmp.getHeight()/bmp.getWidth();

        GoogleMap map = this.getMap();
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Size Screen: "+h+"X"+w+"  "+h2w2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            MarkerOptions mkop = new MarkerOptions();
            place = new LatLng(21+i*0.00055, 105.8+i*0.00054);
            mkop.position(place);
            Marker maker = map.addMarker(mkop);
            maker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, w/20+5, (int)((w/20+5)*h2w2), true)));

        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
// Ha Noi: 21.0226967,105.8369637
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.90, 115.86);
Marker perth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(PERTH)
                          .draggable(true));
```

check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

Comment: please debug the project
I think googleMap is null 
check whether its null or not