# How to get Google map (map_icon, title, latitude, longitude) dynamically from webservice

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps

This is my [web service](https://www.towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=all_products)

where I want to get map_icon, longitude, latitude dynamically from given web service. I am stuck at this point. How can I do this please help me out. 
**In old code what is done is get longitude, latitude, post_title from web service on the basis of id and then assign image statically.**

---

**Frnt_mapActivity.java**

```
public class Frnt_mapActivity extends Activity {

public String Shop_title;
public String Shop_address;
public String Shop_icons;
ProgressDialog mDialog;
JSONObject jsonobject3;
JSONArray jsonarray3;
// Google Map
private static GoogleMap googlemap;
public static ArrayList<SearchBeams> searchdata_list;
public static ArrayList<NormalSearchBeams> normlSearchList;
ArrayList<All_products_lat_long> venueList;

private int i;
private Intent intent;
HashMap<Marker, Integer> hashMap=new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frnt_map_activity);

    googlemap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.places_map)).getMap();
    googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    intent=new Intent(Frnt_mapActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    googlemap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
            i=hashMap.get(arg0);
            intent.putExtra("PRODUCT_ID", venueList.get(i).getId());
            startActivity(intent);
            //overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_left );
        }
    });


    new Frnt_mIcons_Activity().execute();


}

class AddMarkerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    private All_products_lat_long venue;
    private int k;
    BitmapDescriptor bd=null;

    AddMarkerAsyncTask(All_products_lat_long venue,int k){
        this.venue=venue;
        this.k=k;
    }




    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try{
            bd=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Glide.
                    with(Frnt_mapActivity.this).
                    load(venue.getMap_icon()).
                    asBitmap().
                    into(100, 100). // Width and height
                    get());
        }catch (Exception e){
            bd=null;
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try{
            if(bd!=null){
                Marker marker=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(venue.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(venue.getLongitude())))
                        .title(venue.getPost_title())
                        .icon(bd));
                hashMap.put(marker, k);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}


private void addMarkers() {




    for(int k=0; k<venueList.size(); k += 1){

        //nirmal
        try{
            Log.e("nirmal",venueList.get(k).getMap_icon());

            //new AddMarkerAsyncTask(venueList.get(k),k).execute();

            double ln = Double.parseDouble(venueList.get(k).getLongitude());
            double la = Double.parseDouble(venueList.get(k).getLatitude());
                /*String title=venueList.get(k).getPost_title()==null?"":venueList.get(k).getPost_title();
                URL url = new URL(venueList.get(k).getMap_icon());
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                BitmapDescriptor bd=BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image);*/


                /*Marker marker=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                        .title(title)
                        .icon(bd));
                hashMap.put(marker, k);*/

            switch (Integer.parseInt(venueList.get(k).getId()))
            {
                case 5689 :
                    Marker marker=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                            .title(venueList.get(k).getPost_title())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fruitandveg)));
                    hashMap.put(marker, k);
                    break;
                case 5779 :
                    Marker marker1=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                            .title(venueList.get(k).getPost_title())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.coffee)));
                    hashMap.put(marker1, k);
                    break;
                case 5798 :
                    Marker marker3 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                            .title(venueList.get(k).getPost_title())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.takeaway)));
                    hashMap.put(marker3, k);
                    break;
                case 5810 :
                    Marker marker4 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                            .title(venueList.get(k).getPost_title())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.restaurant_steakhouse)));
                    hashMap.put(marker4, k);
                    break;
                case 6005 :
                    Marker marker5 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                            .title(venueList.get(k).getPost_title())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.clambers_playcentre)));
                    hashMap.put(marker5, k);
                    break;
                case 6011 :
                    Marker marker6 = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(la, ln))
                            .title(venueList.get(k).getPost_title())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.thetruecrimemuseum)));
                    hashMap.put(marker6, k);

                    break;
                .........
                ...........
                ............
                default :
                    break;
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("addMarkers",k+"");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

/******************FOR MAP******************/
class Frnt_mIcons_Activity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public ArrayList<All_products_lat_long> maplist;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(Frnt_mapActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }




    // Slow Implementation
    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String s = "";
        String line = "";
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                s += line;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return s;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        maplist = new ArrayList<All_products_lat_long>();

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());



  // Set verifier
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=all_products");

        try{

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            jsonobject3 = new JSONObject(data);
            jsonarray3 = new JSONArray(jsonobject3.getString("all_products"));
            venueList =new ArrayList<All_products_lat_long>();
            for(int j=0; j<jsonarray3.length();j++){
                JSONObject itemobj = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(j);
                //SHOW SEARCH RESULT
                All_products_lat_long searchItems = new All_products_lat_long();

                searchItems.setId(itemobj.getString("ID"));
                searchItems.setPost_title(itemobj.getString("post_title"));
                searchItems.setMap_icon(itemobj.getString("map_icon"));
                searchItems.setLongitude(itemobj.getString("longitude"));
                searchItems.setLatitude(itemobj.getString("latitude"));
                //          System.out.println("######Ashish is object >>"+itemobj);
                venueList.add(searchItems);
                //      System.out.println("SEARCHLISTSS@@@@@@@"+venueList.get(j).getLongitude());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //System.out.println("SEARCHLISTSS@@@@@@@"+venueList);
        //System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+venueList);
        try{
            if(venueList.size()>0)
            {
                addMarkers();
//              Toast.makeText(Frnt_mapActivity.this,"Search for the venue11.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(Frnt_mapActivity.this,"Search for the venue.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(22.75852160, 75.8911550);
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(50.85514, 0.58382);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 18);
            googlemap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray3.length(); i++) {

                jsonobject3 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(i);

                Shop_title = jsonobject3.optString("post_title");
                Shop_address = jsonobject3.optString("map_icon");
                Shop_icons = jsonobject3.optString("map_icon");
                //}
            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing()){
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no icons for markers in Your server response JSON, just references for it. So You should:

1) download JSON response from Your "web service" (for example like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33229869/6950238) question answers, but better use `Service`);

2) for each "ID" of response get icon from URL, stored in "map_icon" field (for example like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5776851/6950238) question answers)

3) create Google Maps marker with icon. downloaded in p.2 like in Your "old code" or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27719572/6950238).

**Update**

There are several issues in Your task:

1) Your server response contains wrong URL's for "map_icon": `http://` protocol prefix instead of `https://`, so You should replace `http://` with `https://`;

2) some of "map_icon" URL's contains UNICODE symbols (like symbol Pound "£" in `save£2.png`), so You should encode it to [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) format: `save%C2%A32.png` instead of `save£2.png`;

3) some of "map_icon" URL's even not exists (like

[`https://towncitycards.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/googlemapicons/save50p.png`](https://towncitycards.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/googlemapicons/save50p.png)
or
[`https://towncitycards.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/googlemapicons/information.png`](https://towncitycards.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/googlemapicons/information.png)) so You should ignore it (or set some default icon for it)

So, according this, described above (before update) steps can be done with `AsyncTask`-based class, like this:

```
protected class CreateProductListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Product>> {

    private String serverUrl;

    public CreateProductListTask(String url) {
        super();
        this.serverUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Product> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {

        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(this.serverUrl);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString());

            List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, Bitmap> iconsMap = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                JSONArray productsJSON = response.getJSONArray("all_products");
                for (int ixProduct=0; ixProduct<productsJSON.length(); ixProduct++) {
                    JSONObject productJSON = productsJSON.getJSONObject(ixProduct);
                    String mapIconStr = productJSON.getString("map_icon");
                    URI uri = new URI(mapIconStr);
                    String[] segments = uri.getPath().split("/");
                    String iconName = segments[segments.length-1];

                    // percetn-encode URL
                    String mapIconPath = mapIconStr.substring(0, mapIconStr.indexOf(iconName));
                    String iconUrlString = mapIconPath + URLEncoder.encode(iconName, "UTF-8");

                    // replace "http:" with "https:"
                    iconUrlString = iconUrlString.replace("http:", "https:");

                    Bitmap bmp;
                    if (!iconsMap.containsKey(iconUrlString)) {
                        bmp = getBitmapFromURL(iconUrlString);
                        // populate map with unique icons
                        iconsMap.put(iconUrlString, bmp);
                    } else {
                        bmp = iconsMap.get(iconUrlString);
                    }

                    if (bmp != null) {
                        try {
                            Product product = new Product();
                            product.name = productJSON.getString("post_title");
                            product.lat = productJSON.getDouble("latitude");
                            product.lon = productJSON.getDouble("longitude");
                            product.icon = bmp;
                            products.add(product);
                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Log.e("App", "Failure", ex);
            }

            return products;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("App", "yourDataTask", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(bufferedReader != null)
            {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Product> products)
    {
        if(products != null) {
            for (Product product : products) {
                googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(product.lat, product.lon))
                        .title(product.name)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(product.icon))
                        );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `Product` class is:

```
protected class Product {
    public String name;
    public double lat;
    public double lon;
    public Bitmap icon;
}
```

`getBitmapFromURL()` is:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bmOptions);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
}
```

}

and You can call it that way (of course after You got reference `googlemap` to `GoogleMap` object):

```
CreateProductListTask responseDownloadTask = new CreateProductListTask("https://www.towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=all_products");
responseDownloadTask.execute();
```

Finally (after 20-30 sec because of server response delay for non existing icons) You got something like that:

[image: Add markers result]

And maybe You need to scale icons like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10413698/6950238) answer of [goodm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014234/goodm)

Of course, this is just example and You need `Service` instead of `AsyncTask` to download data and images from URL (see [Virgil Dobjanschi about patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)).

Comment: how can I create an array of all map_icon and then use in URL as in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url) ?

Comment: or I can do it in some other way

Comment: Sir, you are great.Thank you so much.

Comment: One more thing. I want to increase a size of map_icon how can I do that.Again thank you don't even know how you save me.

Comment: @priya just add `bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(int)(bmp.getWidth()*3), (int)(bmp.getHeight()*3), true);` (where 3 is scale coeff, You can change it to 5 for bigger icons) before `product.icon = bmp;` line. And You also can upvote answer if it so important for You :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont Realy understand Your Question But

u can make

```
Map<String, Marker> markerMap;
```

where String is your ID , or int as your want

then

int your AsynTask to get JSON data

```
 Marker marker = YOURMAP.addMarker(options);
                    marker.setTag(YOUR_ID);
                    //   markers.add(marker);
                    markerMap.put(YOUR_ID, marker);
```

where options is

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                    options.position(YOUR_JSON_OBJECT.Latitude, YOUR_JSON_OBJECT.Longtite));
                    options.title(YOUR_TITLE);
                     options.visible(true);
                         options.icon(YOUR_IMAGE);
```

hope is`s help